# Which MySql function can I use to filter?

Tags: mysql

I want to filter my data in MySql but Idon't know which code or function to use?

I tried ORDER BY i didn't give anything.

Comment: Please take a SQL tutorial. It seems like you are totally new to SQL.

Comment: 'The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected. ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html ALSO search for  sql where

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**ORDER BY** is used to sort your result set.

If you want to filter your data, there are several ways to do so,

You can check out this documentation:
*https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mysql/reading-and-querying-data/filtering-data*

Also, this website is great if you want to learn MySql: *https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/*